# Any gotchas with objc_setAssociatedObject and objc_getAssociatedObject?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I’m looking into ways to add a property (an integer in this case) to all `UIView` instances, whether they are subclassed or not. Is using `objc_setAssociatedObject()` and `objc_getAssociatedObject()` within a category the appropriate, Apple-endorsed way to do this?

I have heard some concerns that this constitutes a “runtime hack,” and can lead to problems that are difficult to track down and debug. Has anyone else seen this type of problem? Is there a better way to add an integer property to all `UIView` instances without subclassing?

**Update:** I can’t just use `tag`, because this needs to be used in a code base that already uses `tag` for other things. Believe me, if I could use `tag` for this, I would!

Comment: A bit late to reply but it might be useful for others who don't want to go so deep and create Categories and new customTag. You can store multiple number in same tag by assigning them at specific digits, for example to assign `view.tag = (view.tag * 100) + myNumber;` and to get it back `myNumber = view.tag % 100` to get original tag, use `originalTag = view.tag / 100`

Comment: Good idea. Depending on what you're doing, you can also use `NS_OPTIONS` and create a bitmask.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Associated objects come in handy whenever you want to fake an ivar on a class. They are very versatile as you can associate any object to that class.

That said, you should use it wisely and only for minor things where subclassing feels cumbersome.

However, if your only requirement is to add an integer to all `UIView` instances, `tag` is the way to go. It's already there and ready for you to use, so there's no need for involving run-time patching of `UIView`.

If you instead want to tag your `UIView` with something more than an integer, like a generic object, you can define a category like follows.

### UIView+Tagging.h

```
@interface UIView (Tagging)
@property (nonatomic, strong) id customTag;
@end
```

### UIView+Tagging.m

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIView (Tagging)
@dynamic customTag;

- (id)customTag {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(customTag));
}

- (void)setCustomTag:(id)aCustomTag {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(customTag), aCustomTag, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

@end
```

The trick of using a property's selector as key, has recently been proposed by Erica Sadun in this [blog post](http://www.tuaw.com/2013/04/10/devjuice-better-objective-c-associated-objects/).

Comment: There is a huge downside to this kind of a pattern, though, in that it leads to *spaghetti code* where your classes and functionality is interleaved with the system classes/functionality such that future refactoring becomes difficult (and maintenance, too).  This *particular* example is relatively harmless, though prefix that property with something unique to your app!

Comment: @bbum, this is the only place where we would use something like this, and it would not get more complicated than @gabriele-petronella’s answer.

Answer (score -2):

Use `tag`. That's what it was meant for.